# What usually happens in a simple blender motor(for making smoothies)

Tags: power

Our 120V blender was plugged in to 220V.

Im trying to take look inside and see if I could give a fix. What is usually the part that gets damaged?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The motor - they don’t usually put fancy protection on cheap devices so buy a new one.

Comment: Also the melted copper part is most likely to be buried deep inside the winding. (According to an amalgamate of Murphy's law and probability)

Answer (score 4):

By connecting a 120 V motor to a 220 V supply you have probably doubled the current through the motor and quadrupled the power dissipated in it. The resultant high-temperature generally lets the smoke out of the windings and once the smoke escapes the motor won't work any more.

[image]

*Figure 1. The built-in smoke escaping a blender motor. This is usually terminal. Image source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vl43HxBnJk). Warning: A blender is harmed in this video.*

In practice the overheating will have destroyed the insulating coating on the copper wires causing internal short-circuits. These will cause a further increase in current ... The burnt insulation gives the characteristic "burnt-out" smell which is often useful in fault diagnosis.  The guy in the video appears to be using a variac to ramp up the voltage. He holds at 130 V and you can hear the hum change over the next few seconds as the insulation breaks down and the short-circuits cause more and more current to flow.

Repair is unlikely.